# Browser error in unobtrusive for asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use unobtrusive Jquery to validate in client side but something is wrong.
the error like the attached image :

[image]

this is my code:

***In BundleConfig.cs**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*", "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));
```

***in the master page :**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

***In view model class :**

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public int? EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(length: 10, ErrorMessage = "First name can't be more than 10 charechers")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = ("First name is required!"))]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(length: 10, ErrorMessage = "First name can't be more than 10 charechers")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = ("Last Nmae is required!"))]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(length: 20)]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [Range(500, 1500, ErrorMessage = "Salare must be between 500 DK and 1500 DK")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = ("Salary is required!"))]
        public double Salary { get; set; }

        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings =false,ErrorMessage =("Email is required!"))]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool IsMarriage { get; set; } = false;
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false,ErrorMessage ="Birth day is required")]
        //[DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

        public TimeSpan? StartWorkingTime { get; set; }

        public TimeSpan? EndWorkingTime { get; set; }
        public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    }
```

***In view :**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save","Employee",FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="form-group ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-form-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(e => e.FirstName, "First Name")
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => Model.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger text-left" })
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.LabelFor(e => e.LastName, "Last Name")
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => Model.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger text-left" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


}
```

**the problem that the client validation not working, but the server side working good

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be a problem with your *MaxLength* attribute syntax. It shoud be

> [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "First name can't be more than 10 charechers.")]

But for client validation, instead of using *MaxLength* attribute, you should try to replace it by *StringLength* attribute.

> [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "First name can't be more than 10
>   charechers.")]    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage =
>   ("First name is required!"))]
>   public string FirstName { get; set; }

Comment: I replace MaxLength by StringLength but it is not working

Comment: Could you try to focus into Salary input, then make it lost focus. Is the Range and Required validators working on this input? If not, is there any script error?

Comment: It is not working too, it gives me the same error of scripting which can't read **call**

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is an year old question however might help someone who might come here looking for answer.
First of all, questioner has not posted the code completely, so it is difficult to arrive at a conclusion why exactly we get error(what is undefined). I do not see the jquery client side validation rules which define the rules and messages for form inputs.
Apart from what he has done, he will need to have client side validation rules as follows:
This example is for a simple registration form which consists are Email, Password and Confirm Password as text input.The code is as follows:

```
$('#registerFormId').validate({  
    errorClass: 'help-block animation-slideDown', 
    // You can change the animation class for a different entrance animation - check 
     animations page  
    errorElement: 'div',  
    errorPlacement: function (error, e) {  
        e.parents('.form-group > div').append(error);  
    },  
    highlight: function (e) {  

        $(e).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-error').addClass('has-error');  
        $(e).closest('.help-block').remove();  
    },  
    success: function (e) {  
        e.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-error');  
        e.closest('.help-block').remove();  
    },  
    rules: {  
        'Email': {  
            required: true,  
            email: true  
        },  

        'Password': {  
            required: true,  
            minlength: 6  
        },  

        'ConfirmPassword': {  
            required: true,  
            equalTo: '#Password'  
        }  
    },  
    messages: {  
        'Email': 'Please enter valid email address',  

        'Password': {  
            required: 'Please provide a password',  
            minlength: 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long'  
        },  

        'ConfirmPassword': {  
            required: 'Please provide a password',  
            minlength: 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long',  
            equalTo: 'Please enter the same password as above'  
        }  
    }  
});
```

Please make sure the names of your text inputs should be same as the properties that you want to validate.
Apart from this make sure Client side validation unobtrusive is enabled in web.config as follows:

Here is an excellent blog post which explains how to implement client and server side validation using jquery unobstrusive validation.

[https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-jquery-form-validator/#:~:text=Server%20side%20form%20validation%2C%20as,with%20ASP.NET%20MVC5%20platform](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-jquery-form-validator/#:%7E:text=Server%20side%20form%20validation%2C%20as,with%20ASP.NET%20MVC5%20platform).

Asma Shaikh
Note : Above blog post is NOT written by me